# Bootstrap-Select dropdown not open

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am trying to create a menu with data-subtext, I have seen some suggestions around on stackoverflow but I cannot get the menu to work. The problem is that the menu doesn't open.

What am I doing wrong ? Code below
Link: https://jsfiddle.net/snake93/mfhvs6xp/55/

I almost forgot, is it possible to remove the black border via css when the menu is active? Example: https://ibb.co/jwWzL7T

```js
$('.strunz').selectpicker();
```

```html
<!--jQuery-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 
<!--BootStrap Select-->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.14.0-beta2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.14.0-beta/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!--BootStrap-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<!--surround the select box with a "custom-select" DIV element. Remember to set the width:-->
  <select class="strunz" data-show-subtext="true" data-size="8">
<option class="optns" data-subtext="Heinz" value="0">Select car:</option>
<option class="optns" data-subtext="Heinz" value="1">Audi</option>
<option class="optns" data-subtext="Heinz" value="2">BMW</option>
<option value="3">Citroen</option>
<option value="4">Ford</option>
<option value="5">Honda</option>
<option value="6">Jaguar</option>
<option value="7">Land Rover</option>
<option value="8">Mercedes</option>
<option value="9">Mini</option>
<option value="10">Nissan</option>
<option value="11">Toyota</option>
<option value="12">Volvo</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: in jsFiddle I saw error in console

Comment: Uh, Thanks for the tip! Popper added, now works fine. But the question of the black border remains, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Add popper under jQuery 3.6.0. Original post edited.

Comment: Yes, i forgot to save fiddle. Now Work.

Comment: here in example(I edited question) it works

Comment: @EmanueleDaniele Yes! you can do it via CSS check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.strunz').selectpicker();
```

```css
.optns {
  background: red;
}

.optns:hover {
  background: black !important;
  color: yellow !important;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 0px !important
}

.dropdown  .bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle:focus, .dropdown  .bootstrap-select>select.mobile-device:focus+.dropdown-toggle, .dropdown .btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
    outline: none !important;
 }
```

```html
<!--jQuery-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!--BootStrap Select-->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.14.0-beta2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.14.0-beta/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!--BootStrap-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<!--surround the select box with a "custom-select" DIV element. Remember to set the width:-->
  <select class="strunz" data-show-subtext="true" data-size="8">
    <option class="optns" data-subtext="Heinz" value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option class="optns" data-subtext="Heinz" value="1">Audi</option>
    <option class="optns" data-subtext="Heinz" value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Citroen</option>
    <option value="4">Ford</option>
    <option value="5">Honda</option>
    <option value="6">Jaguar</option>
    <option value="7">Land Rover</option>
    <option value="8">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="9">Mini</option>
    <option value="10">Nissan</option>
    <option value="11">Toyota</option>
    <option value="12">Volvo</option>
  </select>
```

Add `Popper` under jQuery as you did and for black border add this css

**Popper jQuery**

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown  .bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle:focus, .dropdown  .bootstrap-select>select.mobile-device:focus+.dropdown-toggle, .dropdown .btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
    outline: none !important;
 }
```

Comment: Let me make snippet

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine in your code except you forgot to link `popper.js` cdn link. Use it and your dropdown will work fine. See the preview:

```js
$('.strunz').selectpicker();
```

```css
.optns {
  background: red;
}

.optns:hover {
  background: black !important;
  color: yellow !important;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 0px !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.14.0-beta2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.14.0-beta/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<!--surround the select box with a "custom-select" DIV element. Remember to set the width:-->
<select class="strunz" data-show-subtext="true" data-size="8">
   <option class="optns" data-subtext="Heinz" value="0">Select car:</option>
   <option class="optns" data-subtext="Heinz" value="1">Audi</option>
   <option class="optns" data-subtext="Heinz" value="2">BMW</option>
   <option value="3">Citroen</option>
   <option value="4">Ford</option>
   <option value="5">Honda</option>
   <option value="6">Jaguar</option>
   <option value="7">Land Rover</option>
   <option value="8">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="9">Mini</option>
   <option value="10">Nissan</option>
   <option value="11">Toyota</option>
   <option value="12">Volvo</option>
 </select>
```